# FFMPEG: Converting chapter points when converting PAL to NTSC

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a batch file converting my PAL TV series DVDs to the correct NTSC frame rates:

```
for %%F in (*.mkv) do (
echo A = LWLibAvVideoSource("%%F"^) > script.avs
echo B = LWLibAvAudioSource("%%F"^) >> script.avs
echo AudioDub(A,B^) >> script.avs
echo AssumeFPS(24000,1001,sync_audio=true^) >> script.avs
echo ResampleAudio(48000^) >> script.avs
ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe -i script.avs -aspect 16:9 -acodec ac3 -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -qp 16 "Output\%%F"
del "%%F.lwi"
del script.avs
)

pause
```

But this removes the chapter points. I'm assuming map_chapters, if I figured out how to use it, would just shift in the chapters at the old PAL timestamps, so they wouldn't match up to the correct times in the actual NTSC video? Is there a way to get the chapters in the right spots other than manually opening each episode, finding the equivalent points, and manually creating each chapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mkvmerge's --chapter-sync can handle this:

```
for %%F in (*.mkv) do (
echo A = LWLibAvVideoSource("%%F"^) > script.avs
echo B = LWLibAvAudioSource("%%F"^) >> script.avs
echo AudioDub(A,B^) >> script.avs
echo AssumeFPS(24000,1001,sync_audio=true^) >> script.avs
echo ResampleAudio(48000^) >> script.avs
ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe -i script.avs -aspect 16:9 -acodec ac3 -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -crf 18 "Output\%%F"
mkvextract "%%F" chapters "%%F.txt"
mkvmerge -o "ChapterVersions\%%F" --chapter-sync 0,25000/23976 --chapters "%%F.txt" "Output\%%F"
del "%%F.lwi"
del script.avs
del "%%F.txt"
del "Output\%%F"
)

pause
```